# Scrolling viewpager with sticky TabStrip header

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have an `activity` layout in which I have a `viewpager` that contains a couple of `fragments`. One of the `fragment` holds a `listview` (image sample attached).

What I'm trying to do is to scroll the `listview` and stick the `TabStrip` to the top of the layout, so when you are scrolling the list, the `viewpager`'s fragment titles are always visible but you can see the entire `listview` content.

Above the `viewpager` there are views that needs to scroll up when the `listview` is scrolling.

Is any way to achieve this?

I've tried with `scrollview` and placing the `viewpager` inside it, but it doesn't work because the `viewpager` doesn't display at all.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: are you trying to say that your tabstrip also have to move on scroll on listview?

Comment: the tabstrip has to move from its actual place but just up to the top, and then stay stiky there for scrolling the listview inside the viewpager

Answer (score 2):

i've found the solution by using this nice library from github!!!

[noties/Scrollable](https://github.com/noties/Scrollable)